# Memory leak in GLFW

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, glfw

I have recently started to look into OpenGL for personal pet projects and am writing very simple test programs. However, even with the simplest program I can think of using GLFW, I appear to get a memory leak:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw.h>
int main()
{
  glfwInit();
  glfwTerminate();
}
```

Using valgrind, I get the message:

> definitely lost: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
>
> indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> still reachable: 122,741 bytes in 446 blocks

If I comment out the `glfwTerminate();` line, I get the same number of bytes lost, but several more bytes that are "still reachable" (which makes some sense to me - I haven't terminated GLFW, so whatever memory it's allocated is still there). It appears then, that the memory leak is in `glfwInit()`. Is this a bug in GLFW, or am I doing something terribly wrong even in this simple program?

(Note: A 72-byte memory leak whenever `glfwInit` is called doesn't seem like a huge deal; I'd just prefer that number to be 0...)

Comment: well, valgrind can tell you much more details about where this stuff was allocated. Typically, `xlib` does allocates some stuff which it never frees, so blaming OpenGL here is a bit besides the point. YOur GL implementation might or might not also do this, but there is really nothing you can do about, in both cases.

Comment: @derhass: Allocating stuff you never free is fine so long as you still have access to it (and need it) throughout the program. That's why I don't mind that I have ~120 KB of memory that is still reachable. A leak, though, (denoted by "definitely lost") is Not Good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is a bug in GLFW. [It's been fixed as of 3.2, though](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/pull/662) - I was using GLFW 3.1 when reporting this bug.

Comment: GLFW is not OpenGL

Comment: @derhass: Corrected